# Use right version of Eigen3 with Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen3

I want to use Eigen unsupported modulde NNLS, but in my default version Eigen 3.4.0 I do not have that file, so I downloaded the latest version Eigen 3.4.90 and I installed it using -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/path/to/my/prefix.

To build my project I use Cmake, and my simplified CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.0)
project(my_project VERSION 0.1.0)

find_package(Eigen3 3.4.90 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(my_project ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(my_project PUBLIC
    Eigen3::Eigen
)
```

To check that Cmake found the right version, I checked the variable ${Eigen3_DIR} and I got: /home/path/to/my/prefix/share/eigen3/cmake.

However, I've been unable to use version 3.4.90. Whenever I include

```
#include <eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/NNLS>
```

the compiler (gcc 11.3.0) says that such directory does not exist, and when I write something like

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
```

VScode sends me to the file in usr/include, that is, it detects version 3.4.0.

How can I use the latest version?

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

One option is to replace version 3.4.0 by 3.4.90, but I do not know how to do it correctly. If I just make install version 3.4.90, will it delete automatically the old version?

On the other hand, if in the future I want to keep an old version, I want to learn how to do that.

Comment: Is `/home/path/to/my/prefix` added to the path to search for include files in your compiler?

Comment: I'm guessing problem is order of include paths. Since you have installed Eigen on a system, first Eigen in system include directory is found before your expected version.

Comment: My thinking would be that this is the point where you instead integrate conan or vcpkg with cmake.

Comment: The easiest fix would be uninstall system eigen dev package.

Comment: @NathanOliver when I build my project with Cmake, I pass the flag -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/path/to/my/prefix, so Cmake populates the variable ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} with the right path. Was that your question?

Comment: Yep, missed that.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution (and my rookie mistake). I oversimplified the problem to post it here.

I was using eigen3 in my library

```
My_project/
  |- CMakeLists.txt(*)
  |- main.cpp
  |- lib/
    |- CMakeLists.txt(**)
    |- my_lib.h
    |- my_lib.cpp
```

I used find_package in CMakeLists.txt(*), but I was including it in my_lib.h. I did so because it worked with gnuplot-iostream and sigpack, so I did the same. Now I have

```
    # CMakeLists.txt(**)

    find_package(Eigen3 3.4.90 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)

    add_library(MyLib 
        my_lib.cpp
    )

    target_link_libraries(MyLib PUBLIC
        Eigen3::Eigen
    )
```

Now, I have both versions and when I ask VSCode "go to definition", it sends me to the right version.

To include the file NNLS I type

```
#include <unsupported/Eigen/NNLS>
```

However, it does not find

```
#include <eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/NNLS>
```

The project compiles now fine and it seems that NNLS works right (learning and testing).

Now I wonder why the previous method did not work.